# how to insert update delete within the wpf datagrid itself using mysql i.e editable datagrid

Tags: mysql, wpf, datagrid

i am doing some project for my college using wpf(c#) and mysql and need to use datagrid to display info about students once displayed the admin should be able to insert new info delete and update certain info about students ..
i do not want admin to click on the row, then display data in textboxes and delete or update them from there on clicking a button ...i want to let the admin just delete from the datagrid and type on the datagrid directly over existing data and hit update and reflect that in my database.
i have seen many examples but nothing is working out and this is hindering my project big time
Please help me out

i tried and got this working
http://www.nullskull.com/a/1441/wpf-gridview-sample-to-insert-update-and-delete-records.aspx

but this is through textboxes i need to do it directly through datgrid i.e i need a editable datagrid

now i get the datagrid displayed however the changes i do on datagrid like update a row or delete a row is not reflecting in the database
the code i have done is as follows

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
               using System.Linq;
             using System.Text;
             using System.Threading.Tasks;
             using System.Windows;
             using System.Windows.Controls;
             using System.Windows.Data;
              using System.Windows.Documents;
             using System.Windows.Input;
              using System.Windows.Media;
             using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
             using System.Windows.Navigation;
              using System.Windows.Shapes;
               using MySql.Data;
            using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
              using System.Data;


           namespace testdatagrid
            {

               public partial class MainWindow : Window
                   {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                 bool changingTitle = true; 
                   public MainWindow()
                 {
                   InitializeComponent();

        dataTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dataTable_RowChanged);
        MessageBox.Show("hi");
    }


    void dataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hi");
        if (!changingTitle)
        {
            UpdateDBIssues();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateDBIssues()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hi");
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=deepak230890;pwd=xxxx;database=deepak230890;");
        string updateString = "UPDATE userdata SET id=?id, username=?username, password=?password, WHERE id=?id";
        MySqlCommand updateCommand = new MySqlCommand(updateString, connection);
        updateCommand.Parameters.Add("?id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 100, "id");
        updateCommand.Parameters.Add("?username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "username");
        updateCommand.Parameters.Add("?password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "password");

        MySqlParameter parameter = updateCommand.Parameters.Add("?id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 10, "id");
        parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;

        string insertString = "INSERT INTO userdata (id, username, password) " +
          "VALUES (?id, ?username, ?password)";
        MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySqlCommand(insertString, connection);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("?id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 10, "id");
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("?username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "username");
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("?password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "password");

        adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;

        MySqlCommand deleteCommand = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM userdata WHERE id=?id", connection);
        MySqlParameter delParameter = deleteCommand.Parameters.Add("?id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 10, "id");
        delParameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
        adapter.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand;

        DataTable booksTable = (DataTable)((DataSourceProvider)FindResource("userdata")).Data;
        adapter.Update(booksTable);
    }

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

this is the mainwindow.xaml.cs file

this is the mainwindow.xaml file

```
                  <Window
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    mc:Ignorable="d"

               x:Name="Window"
               x:Class="testdatagrid.MainWindow"
               xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testdatagrid"
               xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                  Title="userdata"
                Width="680" Height="814">

               <Window.Resources>
                   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="userdata"
                 ObjectType="{x:Type local:DatabaseTable}"
                    MethodName="GetTable">
                      <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                        <s:String>SELECT * FROM userdata</s:String>
                        <s:String>username</s:String>
                        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    </ObjectDataProvider>
                </Window.Resources>
                    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource userdata}">
                  <DataGrid x:Name="dataTablegrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"       SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
<!-- Code for UI -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, but takes some effort. It's not straight forward, meaning you have to bind the data source with the Grid and then implement the delete, update functions. there are lot of samples on the net.

The link asked to follow : 
[Example link](http://programming-pages.com/2012/04/13/datagrids-in-wpf/)

You have to do the changes on your code above;

1. In the main window constructor do the following

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataTable dataTable = (DataTable((DataSourceProvider)FindResource("userdata")).Data;
       dataTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dataTable_RowChanged);
       dataTable.RowDeleted += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dataTable_RowChanged);
   }
   ```
2. In the rowchanged event;

   ```
   private void dataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
   {
       UpdateDBIssues();
   }
   ```

I am not sure why you do this check (!changingTitle), In your case it seems not necessary because you haven't used a combo box or a list to change the population of the Grid as is in the example. I tested the code and it works. So with these changes, you will be fine. If it still does not work, Take one command at a time and debug to catch the error. Hope this helps.

XAML: something similar to

```
 <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource dataTable}">
    <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                x:Name="testDataGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

      <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <!--Databound columns-->

       </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i tried the code but i get error here
 objContext = new CompanyEntities();
the name objContext does not exist in the current context 
how to handle this?
i know its lame but i am just starting with datagrids so help me out

Comment: paste some code, and it'll be easier to find the issue

Comment: i have updated the question with the code and answer...is there a way to do this without using the ado.net entity model ..i am using mysql

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you are using mySQL. Then you will not be able to use data context as in EF. Still the update, delete, insert on the grid is possible through data binding. It's just that we connect differently. Use this link (http://programming-pages.com/2012/04/13/datagrids-in-wpf/)

Comment: hey i tried but no success error in xaml ...i have pastedc the code above

Comment: assuming you have all files in one project, and the class DatabaseTable has no compilation errors, I say ignore that error and run the application. I too get this error but it disapears once i run the app

Comment: i ran the app and got the following error     Error           The type reference cannot find a public type named 'DatabaseTable'. Line 17 Position 27.

Comment: is the 'DatabaseTable' class public?

Comment: yup and i get a second error too Error 1                     The name "DatabaseTable" does not exist in the namespace "testdatagrid"

Comment: do u have your 'DatabaseTable' in a different project/dll?

Comment: and correct syntax xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testdatagrid"

Comment: x:Class="testdatagrid.MainWindow"                      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testdatagrid"  these are the only dif I see  use intellicense/auto complete

Comment: no error now app executes but no data is displayed on the wpfform i.e mainwindow.xaml.cs   namespace testdatagrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      
    }
}                                                                       thats all i have in mainwindow.xaml.cs m i missing anything?

Comment: if you have databound your datagrid correctly, it should work.

Comment: eg:  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource TitlesTable}"> <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"...>.....</DataGrid> </Grid>

Comment: i tried what you said and it works but the update delete part isnt reflecting in the database ...i updated the code i am using..what is going wrong?

Comment: I will try this in full and let you know

Comment: do i have to add something for dataTable_RowChanged in xaml file?

Comment: You haven't put the whole code for XAML. So I guessed you got it right. I will update answer again so you can have an idea.

Comment: For the record, dataTable in your case is a datatable we defined in code and bound to dataContext. So no event should be bound from XAML.

Comment: hey i tried what you said ..insert works perfectly. however delete and update have problems ...when i hit delete key the row gets deleted from table but then i get a error i have put the screenshot below

Comment: If "id" is primary key you cant update it so remove it when updatting. And check if your table has relations to other tables, like if "id" is foreign key of another table. If so when deleting you have to handle delete properly (cascade)

Comment: but if  i comment out two lines of code as shown in the screenshot then i can update the username and password but cant update the id which is the primary key what os goin wrong

Comment: ofcourse. That's the ABC of database. Update means you change a record value. Meaning you have to keep the PK as it is. it is PK after all.

Comment: hmmm ok but how do i delete a record in that case?

Comment: the app aint allowing delete

Comment: We are dealing with a disconnected dataset here. So I am guessing (I don't want to believe it but) that you are trying to (may be by mistake) update and delete the same record or the reverse. have a look at this, (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/04/07/concurrency-violation-the-updatecommand-affected-0-of-the-expected-1-records.aspx) and when you get an error try to google it and you'll always get an answer.

Comment: don't know php onlt asp.net html css

Comment: the hyperlinks correspond to files present on ftp server

Comment: m working on building a online directory of exam papers for my college  students get to select the year then the class for which they want to see the paper this is all done i need your help in getting them to download the papers ....after you select the class all the relevent papers get displayed in form of hyperlinks which when clicked allow you to view o download the paper how to go about this?i was thinking of using ftp server(drivehq to be specific)and asp.net website but aint finding good tuts..all the tuts are showing how to download a single specific file not multiple..

Comment: This is an entirely new topic. Post a new question

Comment: i already did   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010498/download-files-using-ftp-asp-net

Comment: hey help me out still cant find any tuts