# download files using ftp asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ftp, download

I'm working on building a online directory of exam papers for my college. Students get to select the year, then the class for which they want to see the paper, this is all done. I don't know how to get them to download the papers. After you select the class all the relevant papers get displayed in form of hyperlinks which when clicked allow you to view or download the paper how to go about this? I was thinking of using ftp server(`drivehq` to be specific)and `asp.net` website but I ain't finding good tutorials. All the tutorials are showing how to download a single specific file not multiple. Do I have to code for every single file present on my server? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide where you are going to save the files. It could be either in a folder on the application root, or if you are going to use SQL FileStreaming(this is very handy as it store the filestream on the table)

I will post a sample code structure to give you a head start, but you will have to figure out how to best fit this to suit your need. I have commented on methods you will have to write, so consider calling web-service methods in these cases in the long run.

I am assuming you have a class alreday created for ExamPaper wich maps to the file you are downloading.

I am getting a list of ExamPapers and binding the list to a datalist which has linkbutton template. And I pass the FileID as a command argument on link button click. Then I store FileID on a session variable. In the newPage, on page load, I simply take that FileID and get relevant data and the stream and append it to response. I am assuming you download word documents, if not you will have to change the Content Type.

Give this a try and if you get any question, try searching on google or ask in this forum.

**code**

ListPage.aspx

```
<asp:DataList ID="PaperList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table">                   
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("FileID")%>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileName")%>' OnCommand ="btnDownload_Command"></asp:LinkButton></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

ListPage.aspx.vb

```
Dim PaperList As New List(Of ExamPaper)

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  'You have to write a method to return the list of file with fileName and the unique id(PK)

  PaperList = GetListofPapers()

  'databind the list
  Me.PaperList.DataSource = DTItems
  Me.PaperList.DataBind()                             

End Sub

Protected Sub btnDownload_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
  Session.Add("FileID", e.CommandArgument)
  Response.Redirect("DownloadDoc.aspx?, False)
End Sub
```

DownloadDoc.aspx.cs

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim fileID = Session.Item("FileID")
  Dim fileInfo As New ExamPaper
  Dim binarystream() As Byte

  ' Methot to get other file Info
  fileInfor = getPaperInfor(FileID) 

  ' write the method to convert file to binary
  binarystream = GetStream(fileID) 

  Response.ClearHeaders()
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfor.FileName )
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-  officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
  If Not binarystream Is Nothing Then
            Response.BinaryWrite(binarystream)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.Close()
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is it better to store the file at the same server where the website is hosted?instead of using ftp or box?what about using mysql to store paths of the file,the file present on same server and then displaying them as hyperlinks in data grid on the website? i cant understand how to get a link(path) for the file to store in db and how to fetch it on site as hyperlink\

Comment: You can save the file on same server. Create an entry in mySQL table with file name and path with a unique ID and primary key. Then this is the list you retrieve to bind to LinkButton. LinkButton is the hyperlink with it's command set(check code above) and clickevent redirecting user to the download page.

Comment: ok thanx il try now and by the way any thoughts on how sites like ssoftonic cnet store their files because they dont redirect you to any  other storage site as such directly downloads happen

Comment: i want my download procedure to look similar to.....click on download link and see     http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-images-using-a-file-path-stored-in-database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: The redirect page close on download/Opening. No offense but you should really write some code and get a basic thing working before speculating. Take one step at a time. And then take your code to next level. No point asking how to do it this way or that way before you get your head around how the basics work.

Comment: Post this hosting part as a new questions. I am not familiar about free hosting. Someone will definitely help you with that. Good luck